# How to post/link an image in a comment

Tags: support, comments, images

It's easy if the image is online, just post the URL in the comment and hit enter - anyone who clicks it will see the image.

Let's say I just photoshopped an image to help explain something to another user and I want to simply post the image as a comment, how do I do that? It's not already online, so there's no link to paste into the comment!

How can I post/link an image in a comment?

Comment: I usually just click "edit" on the question above, add it as a picture, copy-paste the link, then click "cancel"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would follow the strategy laid out in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227089/328832).

- Create a new question or answer (but don't post it!)
- Use the interface provided to upload the image as if you were writing an actual post.
- Then you should have a valid Imgur link to put in your comments.

---

If you would rather not use the SE Imgur account, you could always use your own Imgur account. The link may not remain valid if the image is old and not receiving enough views, though.

Comment: [thanks](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137867/in-the-attack-of-the-clones-poster-made-by-drew-struzan-why-isnt-count-dooku-d#comment348901_137867)

Comment: +1. This is what I've always done.